# How to Access files on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku

I have a project on Heroku. This project allows me to update a JSON file. If update something on Heroku via the project's web interface I see the update. I can close the browser, open it again and the update persists.

Now, I want to push something to this project. If I do, the JSON file will be overwritten. So, I pulled first to get the current project state from heroku. Heroku's prompt says that everything is up to date, which is not true since I changed the JSON file.

Using `heroku run ls static/json/` shows the changed file. I need to get this file before pushing to heroku to avoid destroying updates done via the web interface.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, for one reason: A Heroku dyno has it's own [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) with a git checkout of the most recent code. It cannot go the other way around however, it's not possible to check file changes in the dyno in into the git repo. This is why you get the response 'Already up-to-date.' when trying to pull, because the heroku git remote is inn sync with your local repo.

You should maybe store your file on Amazon's S3 or in a database or even write your data to a database, so that it is persisted between heroku deployments.

Answer (score 4):

You can run `heroku run bash` and backup the file then deploy your app run `heroku run bash` again and remove the new file and replace it with the old one you backed up. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check your files in your last deploy, you can run `heroku run bash --app your-app-name`. 
However if you upload files programmatically to your app like submitting a form with a file within it, these files will disappear after a while as [herok doc](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted) mentions

> The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many container based systems, such as Docker, operate.
> In addition, under normal operations dynos will restart every day in a process known as "Cycling".