# How to see files and file structure on a deployed Heroku app

Tags: bash, heroku

My client app that is deployed on Heroku allows the user to upload images onto Heroku.  I wanted to test out a change I made to delete images, so I need a way to see the state of the folder structure on Heroku to ensure the images are being deleted successfully of the file system.

I tried -

```
$ heroku run bash --app <appName>
~$ pwd
~$ cd <path to images folder>
```

but I only see images here that I uploaded along with the app, not what was uploaded through the client app.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763440/how-to-access-files-on-heroku

Answer (score 315, accepted):

I can do with this commands

```
heroku login
heroku run bash -a APPNAME
$ cd app
```

`APPNAME` is the name of your Heroku application And in the folder `app` are your files.

When you finish your commands and want to return to your terminal you can write

```
$ exit
```

Comment: not working on mac. we should pass the app name on the same line heroku run bash --app

Comment: heroku run bash --app your-app-name

Comment: @HMagdy Actually this is correct only if you are in your current working directory. It is important to note that this working directory should be linked with Heroku. Meaning that you must have pushed its contents to heroku master. You only need the -app-name flag if you are not in the working directory.

Comment: C:\Users\user>heroku run bush --app fast-island-39166
Running bush on ⬢ fast-island-39166... up, run.2379 (Free)
bash: bush: command not found

- here is what going on on windows!!!

Comment: after start a session with heroku login and then run the command heroku run bash --app your-app-name, work for me as said in the answer.

Comment: Your application may not reside in an "app" folder. Run "dir" (or "ls") to see folder structure. In the case of worker bots, there may simply be some files there.

Comment: Its says : *Error: Cannot find module '/app/bash'*

Answer (score 36):

Terminal access is now provided by clicking a link "More" on the top right of the Heroku dashboard where you can select "run console".
This presents an option to run terminal commands and shows a default of 'bash'. However, you do have to explicitly enter 'bash' or other command.
If you edit files, you will have to manage synchronization back to your development code using Git.

Answer (score 10):

As in @Juliano Araújo's answer but from a project folder connected via git you can just run
`heroku run bash`

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with,

```
heroku run bash -a APPNAME
```

If the above command fails,

```
heroku run sh -a APPNAME
```

Answer (score 3):

`

- **app settings option gives our files url**

` [image: settings]

### Then use git clone

- `git clone https://git.heroku.com/your_app_name.git`